# How to check if an actor is inside of sphere

Tags: game-development, unreal-blueprint, unreal

I have a player object in my game. I want to be able to check or the player is inside of an invisible sphere (like a noncollidable trigger) so I can do actions after player is in sphere

By the way i use blueprints **(NOT c++)** so please provide an explanation on how to do this with blueprints

Please explain in a beginner friendly way because I am new to unreal

I didn't try anything because I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward to do. On your `Actor` which is trying to detect the player, add a `Sphere Collision` component:
[image]

Then, with the component selected, click the `+` sign on the `On Component Begin Overlap` Event under the `Events` category:
[image]

You should be able to get overlap events with other information to help you identify when the player overlaps with the sphere.